# Microsoft Flow - Decode 'File Content' Property (SharePoint Trigger)

Tags: power-automate

We're building a custom connector for Microsoft Flow and hoping someone could help clarify exactly how Flow is encoding the File Content property found in the following SharePoint Trigger: 'When a file is created or modified'

We can see from the request sent to our EndPoint:

- The content type is set as: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
- The JSON is correctly formed containing an encoded string for the File Content property

However, we can't find a way to successfully decode the string (assuming it's Base64)... the error message:

"The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters"

Any guidance on how to correctly the data = (ASPNet Core 2 API) to a byte array would be much appreciated.

Big thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
var DeodedText = "put your encoded text here";
byte[] imageBytes=Convert.FromBase64String(DeodedText);

FileInfo file = new FileInfo("your path /filename.extension");

file.Directory.Create();

File.WriteAllBytes("your path /filename.extension", imageBytes);
```

Comment: Please don't simply post code, explain what it does and how it solves OPs problem.